# How to extract Cognito's domain name using NodeJs and AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to write an automation script to compose the data needed for a process to authenticate itself against a Cognito user pool.

By that I mean I'm trying to extract the credentials from a Cognito user pool. This includes ClientId, ClientSecret, and the URL to send an OAuth2 request to. The first two, I can extract using the [CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.describeUserPoolClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#describeUserPoolClient-property) API. But I could not find the API to return back the domain name for the Cognito user pool. Does anyone know how to find a user pool's domain name using NodeJs and AWS SDK?

For clarification, I'm trying extract the following domain name for a specific user pool (using a user pool ID):

`https://<arbitrary-subdomain>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUserPoolDomain.html

Comment: @MarkB Thanks. I've already seen that but it's taking the `Domain` as an input! I don't have the domain.

Comment: DescribeUserPool gives the domain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUserPool.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, I don't know how I missed that!